# Short story about man who finds vial containing “wick” which, when extended, absorbs all ambient sound. Disaster follows

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Man discovers vial with wick that has the incredible property of absorbing all ambient sound when extended from vial.  Man becomes addicted to silence & overuses wick with disastrous consequences.

The depiction of how the man began using the wick sparingly—but gradually became consumed by his need for silence—was exceedingly well-developed.

There’s a limit to how much I can add;  I read the story just once, at least 30 years ago.  I believe it was quite short, 10 pp or less.  I think it was in an anthology, though it might have been a collection by one author.

SPOILER FOLLOWS:

> The wick can be extended gradually, and the “quieting power” is directly proportional to wick exposure.  The man who found the wick eventually abuses it by operating at maximum all the time, absorbing all sound in his vicinity.  He overloads the device, which abruptly releases all the acoustic energy it has accumulated.  I can’t recall the specific consequences, but they were unpleasant.

I hope to find & read again…

Comment: Welcome to SFF, worksong. Lovely first question! Can you edit to tell us what year or decade you encountered this story?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: What were the "disastrous consequences"?

Comment: There's a Clarke story called "Silence Please" that features a sound absorber that blows up at the end. It does not work by a wick though, so I haven't posted as an answer. But your edit about the explosion makes me unsure now.

Comment: The Clarke story is an excellent suggestion...but this protagonist is definitely a finder, not an inventor.  He has no idea how the device does what it does (which is one reason he doesn't understand it has limits).

Comment: Was the wick device called "silentzia" ? It sort of looked like a room deodorizer. I remember the story, but not the name nor author. Eventually the wick overloaded and exploded. The inventor catches up with the protagonist, and gives him a supply to buy his silence.

Comment: @WinchellChung You should post that as an answer. "Silenzia" is the name of the story, by Alan Nelson, you can read it here: https://archive.org/details/Fantasy_Science_Fiction_v005n03_1953-09/page/n62/mode/1up

Comment: Nicely done @WinchellChung and @user14111!

Comment: Amusingly, the concept of a filament-based storage device that soaks up sound, becomes overloaded and emits all the sound at once in a blast also comes up in "[Joshua's Battering Ram](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?834909)" (1940) by Malcolm Jameson, republished in the [collection of stories eligible for the 1941 retro-Hugo](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?760425).

Comment: Argh. I couldn't find it with a search because I misspelled 'Silenzia' as 'Silentzia'

Comment: There's a story on a similar theme about a man so irritated by constant advertising that he has his hearing surgically removed.   But the one good thing in his life, his fantasy dream woman, becomes dumb...

Answer (score 39, accepted):

[Silenzia](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?74060) by Alan Nelson (1953)

Protagonist is in a pawnshop and discovers what looks like an old bottle of Air Wick room deodorizer. But the label says Silenzia. It has the power of neutralizing the noise pollution so irritatingly prevalent in the big city. The protagonist overuses it, and barely manages to throw the bottle away before it explodes

Disappointed protagonist is covertly contacted by the secret society that uses Silenzia, and is given a supply in exchange for keeping the secret.

Story can be read [here](https://archive.org/details/Fantasy_Science_Fiction_v005n03_1953-09/page/n62/mode/1up)

Comment: And there’s a fascinating topical tidbit at the end of the Internet Archive’s copy of this story: a polio PSA.  “POLIO Research will mean Victory!  // GAMMA GLOBULIN — obtained from human blood — protects for a few weeks.  But it is in *very short supply.* // When POLIO is around, follow these PRECAUTIONS: 1 Keep clean. 2 Don’t get fatigued. 3 Avoid new groups. 4 Don’t get chilled. // A VACCINE is not ready for 1953. But there is hope for the future. // The National Foundation for Infantile Paralysis”

Comment: I've wanted to re-read this story for longer than I care to admit, & am both impressed & grateful that it was so quickly found.  Thanks to all who pitched in!

Comment: @PLL Nowadays we'd have ads telling people to go out and get polio deliberately, to stop the country  turning into North Korea.

Comment: @user253751 I think you mean "we've", not "we'd have".

Comment: @MatthewWells "we'd have" = "we would have"

Comment: @user253751 "Would" implies that we don't.

Comment: @MatthewWells No magazine ads, just Internet propaganda. (Not Internet ads, either. Or at least I haven't seen any. They want it to look like a grassroots movement, see)

Comment: I had no idea Air Wick had been around that long, founded in 1943 according to Wikipedia.  So it was probably just starting to become common when this was written.  For some reason I just thought of them as a newer company.

Comment: Silly protagonist, he could've just left the cap off the bottle and left it in the car and it wouldn't have exploded. What did he think would happen when he put the cap on a bottle of boiling liquid? His own fault, really.

Answer (score 6):

The episode with the sound-absorbing wick that I recall, comes from the movie,
**The 5000 Fingers of Doctor T**, a Stanley Kramer opus with a Dr. Seuss script.

When curious about the potency of that little sound absorber, Bart
asks "Is it atomic?"... the reply "Yes, very atomic!"

Comment: This was never a short story, but it was the first thing I thought of when I read the question, too -- and I'll never be able to think of that movie without recalling the "Siamese twins" -- roller skating old men, joined at the beard!?